# i386 MacMini - maximum RAM Upgrade

Tags: mac, memory, upgrade, mac-mini

I do use MacMini having Core2Duo Processor ( 2.4 Ghz ).
I am going to upgrade RAM of my MacMini.
Currently It has 2 slots of RAM memory. It has 2GB right now. 1GB per slot.
I am going to buy a new 4GB for a single slot.

Means

- 4GB per a slot
- 1GB per a slot

I have heard that, 32 Bit OS doesn't support more than 4GB. Is it the same case here ?

To find out the architecture of my Mac OS, I used Following command.

`uname -p`

It shows me i386, It means MacOSX is running 32Bit operating system.
Will there be any problem while upgrading RAM ?

Summarizing My Question

- What is the maximum RAM support in macMini ? ( MacMini 4.1 - new version of macMini)
- Does os architecture is a constraint while upgrading RAM ?
- Does above constraint is applicable to current case ? How ?

Thanks for sharing your great knowldege.

Comment: Seems kind of silly, but whenever I need to know the max RAM for a box, I ask Crucial.com.  They sell great RAM at a good price with lifetime warranty, and they have a tool to identify your system as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Mac Mini is the current model, then Apple states that it will hold up to 2x4GB of memory, so you should be able to do what you planned.

You're correct that a 32-bit OS will be limited to a maximum of 4GB of memory usage. It seems that the Mac Mini 4.1 comes with both 32-bit and 64-bit OS kernels, but the 32-bit might be enabled by default. If so, you can [change which kernel is booted](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3773).